# Why puts function doesn't work with input char from socket in C++?

Tags: c, sockets, concatenation, c-strings, null-terminated

This is my code for a server running a login manager, that log into a file the malicious access and print out the result of the wrong login.
The chars user and pass come from the user input using the socket.

```
if ((memcmp(user, "admin", strlen("admin")) == 0)) {
    /*code... */
}
else {
    char msg[600];
    strcpy (msg,"Login error with ");
    strcat (msg,"user: ");
    strcat (msg,user);
    strcat (msg," password: ");
    strcat (msg,pass);
    strcat (msg," from: ");
    strcat (msg, client_ip);
    puts (msg);
    logfile->Write(msg);
    return false;
}
```

Well, the problem is the output both on the output console and in the logfile.

Like this:

```
Login error with user: lol

 password: asd

:��ܔ��P{w� from: 127.0.0.1
```

Why are there the strange asci chars?
How can avoid the new line since they come from user input by socket?

Comment: Fix your formatting yourself next time, please!

Comment: Unrelated / suggestion: Why not just use `strcmp(user, "admin") == 0`?

Comment: You tagged this C++. I wonder why you're not using C++'s `std::string`. Looks like there are three possible buffer overflow situations in your code, and they wouldn't be there if you used `std::string`. The *Morris worm*, the *Code Red Worm*, the *SQL Slammer* worm (and others) are famous pieces of malware that took advantage of buffer overflows.

Comment: This is not C++. Throw the code away, and start over.

Comment: Is not the problem, but strcmp not working in this case with an input coming by a socket.

Comment: `pass` is probably not null terminated ... for the record don't write code like this and call it C++

Comment: I'll retag it C since there is nothing C++ specific going on here.  Other parts of the code may use `iostream` classes but that isn't surfaced in the example.

Comment: Two C strings walk into a bar.  One says "I'll have a brew.Sk3Q#UV%2o4ho!/"  The other says "Please excuse my friend, he's not null-terminated."

Answer (score 2):

As multiple people have commented about, this snippet of code contains nothing C++ specific, so I'm answering as if you are working in plain C.

I'm guessing, since you use `memcmp` above, that your input strings are not null terminated.  `strcat` will keep on appending `char`s from whatever the pointer wanders into until it runs into a `'\0'`.  You'll need to add a null terminator if you want to use user or password as a C-style string, or else use [`strncat`](http://goo.gl/fu27I) and pass the length.

Also, beware of overrunning `msg`.  You might have better luck using [`snprintf`](http://goo.gl/0WLU4) to format your message, since it accepts a maximum output string length.

Comment: Ok I've learned reading the comments before, that this cannot be called C++ code. That's right is the pure C style and is not good for my goal, so I used std:string library.

Comment: pure C is OK, you just don't understand how to use it the right way

Answer (score 1):

This way you could make your code little bit smaller

```
if (strcmp(user, "admin") == 0) {
    /* yahoo, admin! */
}
else {
    char buff[256];
    snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff),
            "Login error with user: %s password: %s from: %s",
            user,
            pass,
            client_ip);
    printf("%s\n", buff);
    logfile->Write(buff);
    return false;
}
```

adding this extra code before if-statement you could ensure strings are valid

```
printf("user, len:%d, value: %s\n", strlen(user), user);
printf("pass, len:%d, value: %s\n", strlen(pass), pass);
printf("client_ip, len:%d, value: %s\n", strlen(client_ip), client_ip);
```

Comment: `printf("%s\n", buff)`?  Why not just `puts(buff)`?

Comment: Well...the result is the same.

user, len:11, value: superuser


pass, len:16, value: password

�����
client_ip, len:9, value: 127.0.0.1
Login error with user: superuser

 password: password

����� from: 127.0.0.1

Incredible...I see always the asci code and there is still the /n.
Is it possible solve this?

Comment: I've noticed that the char* password is always of 16 length!
How is it possible?
Only whan I type a string > 14 no strange asci chars.
But user and password are the same...incredible.
How can I solve this?

Comment: your 'pass' string is not null-terminated, double check how do you create it